# Where in System Settings do I set a static IP?

Tags: networking, kubuntu, 15.04, ip, static-ip

I can't find where you can set a static IP in the network settings.

[image: Network Settings]

Anywhere top level?

[image: System Settings Top Level]

Comment: I think it is in Connection Preferences.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a good place to upload pictures to illustrate, but I'll try to talk you through it as best I can. I downloaded a copy of Kubuntu 15.04 just so I could help you with this!

In order to access the network settings for a specific connection and add a static IP, do this:

1. Click the network connection indicator in the system tray
2. You should see something like Wired Connection 1 (I'm doing this from a VM, so please adjust accordingly)
3. Select that connection and in the upper right of that dialog, click the  button that looks like two sliders. This will open up the advanced options for that connection.
4. Select the connection in the list and hit the edit button at the top.
5. Select the applicable tab, IPv4 or IPv6 and change the Method combo box to Manual.
6. Then add your static IP information (IP address, netmask, and gateway) into the listbox at the bottom by pressing the "+ Add" button.
7. Add your DNS servers as well and you should be all set!

Comment: Bingo! That did the trick. thank you very very much. Not obvious but not too hard.

Comment: In my limited experience with KDE, it seems that things usually aren't obvious. You'd do be a big favor but selecting my answer as the best answer.

Comment: The above directions did not work for me (kubuntu 16.04) until I disabled the adapter, then edited the config, then enabled the adapter.  Otherwise, the changes would not persist.

Answer (score 0):

For `cpe:/a:kde:plasma-workspace:5.27.10`:

1. Invoke *System Settings* (`systemsettings5`);
2. Access *Connections* (`kcmshell5 kcm_networkmanagement`);
3. Select the network;
4. Choose IPv4 or IPv6; and
5. Select the *Manual* method:

   > [image]

   However, [how to *use* the IPv6 panel is not obvious to me, due to the values it (dis)allows.](https://discuss.kde.org/t/how-to-set-a-static-ipv6-address-i-cant-enter-one/10657?u=rokejulianlockhart)